# Difference between "senza pericoli" and "senza pericolo"

Tags: word-choice, difference

I have read the following sentence:

> I bambini possono giocare senza pericoli qui

Would "senza pericolo" have the exact same meaning of "senza pericoli" in this sentence? Is the former as usual as the latter?

Comment: Yes they convey the same meaning. Both expressions are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by Gio in his comment, both these expressions are used to convey the same meaning. According to [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=senza+pericolo%2Csenza+pericoli&year_start=1980&year_end=2018&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csenza%20pericolo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csenza%20pericoli%3B%2Cc0) it seems that "senza pericolo" is more used than "senza pericoli".

To give some examples of use, you can find "senza pericolo" in this definition of the word "sicuro" given by [Garzanti dictionary](https://sapere.virgilio.it/parole/vocabolario/sicuro)

> che è senza pericolo

in this quotation from [*I promessi sposi* by Alessandro Manzoni](https://books.google.es/books?id=d9SdAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22Mentre+quel+forno+veniva+cos%C3%AC+messo++sottosopra,+nessun+altro+della+citt%C3%A0+era+quieto+e+senza+pericolo%22&source=bl&ots=Clxx3knIyh&sig=ACfU3U129P1tKezNAsV3sQVK7CJARewMUA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8vOnc8MDkAhXFAWMBHVNIDDEQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Mentre%20quel%20forno%20veniva%20cos%C3%AC%20messo%20%20sottosopra%2C%20nessun%20altro%20della%20citt%C3%A0%20era%20quieto%20e%20senza%20pericolo%22&f=false)

> Mentre quel forno veniva così messo  sottosopra, nessun altro della città era quieto e senza pericolo

or in this one from [*Settantacinque racconti* by Corrado Alvaro](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI02/GDLI_02_ocr_119.pdf&parola=pericolo)

> L’artista è il solo che possa dire di sé  senza  pericolo,  il  solo  che  possa manifestare  tutto  quello  che  ha  dentro,  e  tutti  gli  battono le  mani.

"Senza pericoli" is, for instance, used by [Enrico Pea in *Il trenino dei sassi*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI01/GDLI_01_ocr_450.pdf&parola=pericoli)

> L'andare a  caccia  non  costituiva  dunque  privilegio, né  per  i  ricchi  né  per  i  poveri,  né  per  chi  era religioso  o no, perché  andavano  a  caccia  anche  gli  anarchici,  che  in  quel tempo  nel  mio  paese  ce  n’era  più  di  uno

and by [Arturo Loria in *Il compagno dormente*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI06/GDLI_06_ocr_593.pdf&parola=pericoli)

> S’udirono   in fondo  le  imprecazioni  e  gli  urli  dell’impresario  per  ga­rantirsi   un   passaggio   senza   pericoli.

You can find it also in the book [*Genitori* by Sergio Felleti](https://books.google.es/books?id=3W0zDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=senza+pericoli%22&source=bl&ots=-v0SNy4vjl&sig=ACfU3U0cKvZ3aBY495u73TPIyDHdotcHsA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_sruAoL7kAhWB34UKHRvqCOAQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ):

> I genitori devono mettere a disposizione dei propri figli un ambiente sicuro e senza pericoli​.